# Impersonating the non domain user account in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I wanted to impersonate the User who is in abc domain from the xyz domain user in asp.net.
If possible please paste the code.

Comment: Does this need to be dynamic based on the user who is signed in? As in, does ABC\User1 need to map to XYZ\User1? Or something of that nature?

Answer (score 0):

In web.config

```
<identity impersonate="true"
         userName="domain\user" 
          password="password" />
```

Comment: This code works only when user is in domain. Not in non domain user. It gives exception as "Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship."